# Complexity analysis after multiplication of two functions

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Given F(n) = θ(n)

H(n) = O(n)

G(n) = Ω(n)

then what will be order of F(n) + [G(n) . H(n)] ?

edit: F(n) = θ(n) not Q(n)

Comment: Thos should be asked on another math-focused StackExchange site.

Comment: Sounds like homework. What are your findings so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: what's the meaning of the dot notation in `G(n) . H(n)`? is that a product?

Comment: I've understood that for addition, the maximum of the asymptotic values is taken but when multiplying two functions like O(n)*Ω(n) how should we think about it?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin, yes that's a product of two functions.

Comment: I am not exactly fresh on this, but Ω(n) is really a vague indication, it says that the running time of *G(n)* is larger or equal to *k \* f(n)* for some *k*, but that could be said about any quadratic function too - as far as I remember. Thus I think that you could conclude  *F(n) + [G(n) \* H(n)]* being in Ω(n^2). But I am very open to being disproved, I don't claim to remember this subject too well after half a decade.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't enough information to say anything about the function `P(n) = G(n)*H(n)`. All we know is that `G` grows *at least* linearly; it could be growing quadratically, cubically, even exponentially. Likewise, we only know that `H` grows *at most* linearly; it could only be growing logarithmically, or be constant, or even be *decreasing*. As a result, `P(n)` itself could be decreasing or increasing without bound, which means the sum `F(n) + P(n)` could also be decreasing or increasing without bound.

Suppose, though, that we could assume that `H(n) = Ω(1)` (i.e., it is at least not decreasing). Now we can say the following about `P(n)`:

```
P(n) = H(n) * G(n)
     >= C1 * G(n)
     = Ω(G(n)) = Ω(n)

P(n) <= C1*n * G(n)
      = O(n*G(n))
```

Thus `F(n) + P(n) = Ω(n)` and `F(n) + P(n) = O(n*G(n))`, but nothing more can be said; both bounds are as tight as we can make them without more information about `H` or `G`.

Comment: I don't understand `P(n) <= C1*n * G(n) = O(n * G(n))`. Are you saying that from `H(n) = Ω(1)` we can *safely* assume that `H(n) <= C1*n`, or did I misunderstand your example? Isn't `Ω(1)` a much weaker bound, that only imposes `H(n)` to be at least `C1` but it doesn't truly pose an upper limit on it? I'm fairly rusty on the subject, so please forgive me the trivial question. *(suggested edit: separate example part  in which you assume `H(n) = Ω(1)` from the initial explanation with a line break)*

Comment: `Ω(1)` and `O(n)` are completely independent bounds. For the `<=` case, I am using `O(n)`; for the `>=` case, `Ω(1)`. Without the assumed `Ω(1)`, `H(n)` can partially or completely "cancel out" the growth of `G(n)` when the two are multiplied.

Comment: *Bingo!* Thanks, I slipped over the question's input when I came back to your answer a day later. ;)